# iTunes App Store Language String

Tags: iphone, ios4, itunes, app-store-connect

I would like to know where is the correct place to put the available languages of an app so they show at the iTunes App Store app description.

Some peeps here at SO say it should be at the binary while others say it is at the iTunes Connect Site.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is probably both of those.

If you localize files in your app within Xcode and populate the InfoPlist.strings files correctly, then assuming the iOS device's system language changes then it will load them when your app is launched. You must also correctly setup your app's localizations within iTunes Connect as well, so that you can upload your description & screenshots (etc) in their localized formats too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just uploaded an app to iTunes Store. It is in Spanish, but in the store it says "Language:English". How do I change that? I dont want to use Localized stuff. Do you know?

Answer (score 0):

If you already uploaded your app to iTunes connect and you just want to show app description/screen shots in other language then follow this steps to add languages.

```
1. Open iTunes connect
2. Manage your Applications
3. Select your app and Click on View Details Button.
4. Click on Manage Localization button on right top side.
5. Click on Add Languages.
6. You will then redirect to select/fill up all the details for new language.
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This shows: "You cannot add a new language from this page because your app has either already been approved or is currently in review. To add a new language, you must submit a new version of your app." Thanks anyways.

Comment: Oh so you already uploaded binary as well? You may need to reject that binary. do necessary changes and upload same version again if it is not much headache for you:). because I guess this is the only way as per my knowledge.